# *** stack smashing detected ***: <unknown> terminated Aborted (core dumped)

Tags: c

I'm trying to make a program that reads an array with 15 elements and outputs the numbers in that array only one time for each kind of number (repetitions don't get outputted). I'm getting the error in the title and I don't know why. Here's my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void main () {

    int initial[15], final[15], nf=1, aux;

    printf("Insert the 15 elements:\n");

    for (int i = 0; i < 15; ++i)
    {
        printf("Insert the %dº element:\n",i+1);
        scanf("%d", &initial[i]);
    }

    final[0]=initial[0];

    for (int i = 1; i < 15; ++i)
    {

        for (int k = 0; k < nf ; ++k)
        {   
            if (initial[i]!=final[k]) {

                final[nf]=initial[i];
                nf++;
            }
        }
    }

    for (int c = 0; c < nf ; ++c)
    {
        printf("%d, ",final[c]);
    }

}
```

Comment: what do you use compiler ? which version ? what have you tried to understand your problem ? what can you find in debug ?

Comment: Typical symptom of writing out of bounds of a local array.

Comment: Add `printf` to watch the value of `nf` as you are incrementing it. I bet it's reaching `15` at some point.

Comment: a suggested, take a close look at your variables in your loops using debugger. (to me, console prints are just stone-age debug)

Comment: @Asu Tried your suggestion and indeed, nf went to 85. But it should only increment if the number from the initial array is different from the numbers in the final one, right?

Comment: You smash the stack by writing beyond an array[] bound.  assert(nf < 15); will show you the bug.

Answer (score 3):

Your logic for the inner loop is flawed. The condition `initial[i]!=final[k]` would be satisfied when elements are different which is not what you want. You want to check if `initial[i]` is present in the `final` array.

```
for (int i = 1; i < 15; ++i)
{
    bool found = false;
    for (int k = 0; k < nf ; ++k)
    {
        if (initial[i]==final[k]) {
            found = true;
            break; // Found a dup, no need to continue further.
        }
    }

    // Not present in final array, so include it.
    if (!found) final[nf++] = initial[i];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Without considering what you want to really do with your arrays, some potential flaws are explained below.
You would have seen that cristal clear in debug mode watching for `k`, and `nf` values changes. Or with console prints.

```
for (int k = 0; k < nf ; ++k) { // risky algorithm: k used as index of array, with no array bound check
    if (initial[i]!=final[k]) { // risk here with k, uncheked array index: what if k > array length ?
        final[nf]=initial[i]; //  risk here with nf, uncheked array index: what if nf > array length ?
        nf++; // risky algorithm: for loop stop condition is changed at each iteration
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this algorithm. Hopefully it might work:

```
def firstNonRepeating(arr, n): 

for i in range(n): 
    j = 0
    while(j < n): 
        if (i != j and arr[i] == arr[j]): 
            break
        j += 1
    if (j == n): 
        return arr[i] 

return -1
```